# websnapr change in API?

Tags: api, snapshot

I'm currently using the websnapr code to include the screen shots of some site in my site.
The code is

```
<img border=0 src="http://images.websnapr.com/?size=S&key=api_key&url='mysite.com'"/>
```

But now websnapr.com change the code to include an additional parameter 'hash', in the above code. I cannot find out how to specify the hash through my code automatically every time.
What is the right code?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the Hash like this

```
<img border=0 src="'http://images.websnapr.com/?url=' + url + '&key=' + apiKey + '&hash=' + encodeURIComponent(websnapr_hash)"/>
```